# Twitter4j 401 Authentication

Tags: java, android

This is the code that is causing the problem. And below is the Logcat. I have printed the exception. I have checked the consumer and secret keys multiple times. Could anyone shed anymore light or how to get more details on this issue?

I should also mention that I have run this script on the emulator and a real phone, both bring back the same logcat

```
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680): 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680): Failed to validate oauth signature and token
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680): Relevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=10f5ada3 or
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=dceba039
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[10f5ada3-dceba039], statusCode=401, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.4}
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:185)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:102)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:121)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:104)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:276)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at com.blundell.tut.ttt.TweetToTwitterActivity.loginNewUser(TweetToTwitterActivity.java:109)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at com.blundell.tut.ttt.TweetToTwitterActivity.buttonLogin(TweetToTwitterActivity.java:83)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2077)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2461)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8890)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
09-21 15:27:25.504: ERROR/HelloWorld(17680): 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret
```

You have entered wrong **Consumer Key** or **Secret Key** from your Created Application in Twitter.

Ensure that you gave the two keys also ensure that it is correct.

For Further Reference Check this [Integrating Twitter with Android](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application)

Comment: Thanks after double checking again I noticed some whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, you`ve created a desktop application. Change type of your app on browser app.
This is good tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

look at **My application setting** and **Application type**

Access:

- Read only
- Read and Write
- Read, Write and Access direct messages

What type of access does your application need? Note: `@Anywhere` applications require **read & write** access.

Find out more about our **Application Permission Model**.

Default is read only   please select read and write and again.

Answer (score 0):

Well my **device's date was incorrect**. Seemed strange but, it did work. When the date was set correct it worked fine. You may show an alert asking the user to check the device current date and/or time.